# conversion of time into minute count

Tags: sql, datetime, datetime-format, valueconverter

Ok so I need to convert a value from a table into an absolute minute count. 
What I mean by that is this.

I currently have data like this

> ID   day  time
>
> > 1   1  00:04
> >
> > 2   1  01:08
> >
> > 3   2  00:08
> >
> > 4   2  02:04

I want it to convert to total count of minutes, not resettting back to zero for each day. so it would be

> ID   day  time
>
> > 1   1  04
> >
> > 2   1  68
> >
> > 3   2  1448
> >
> > 4   2  1564

Currently the time data is varchar(5) and not in date time. I have tried

DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,dispatchday), 0), dispatchday)

and that returned nothing but zero's

Comment: This looks like sql server??? Why are you using varchar to store time data? You should be using the time datatype. If I understand correctly you just want to add (Day - 1) * 1440 + (Hours * 60) + Minutes? What is this dispatchday? Can you provide ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: I know it shouldn't be in varchar, but that's what Im given. Dispatchday is the equivalent of daynumber, i just couldn't use something as generic as Day in sql for obvious reasons. Your formula is correct, Im just having problems converting my varchar to hours and minutes.

Comment: Without something to work with I can't do it either. :) Just cast that varchar to a time datatype and grab the portions you need for your formula. Hopefully your data is all valid.

Comment: Also if you cast the time as a TIME datatype, you don't need to do the DATEADD(DATEDIFF()) trick.   You can just do DATEDIFF(minute,0,[Time])

Comment: I figured it out, instead of converting to datetime, I just use LEFT(time,2) as hours and Right(time,2) as minutes. then use your formula.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server I presume? This should take care of it. It doesn't make a difference what kind of field time is in, as long as it contains a valid time value.

```
select (day-1) * 1440 + datediff(minute, '00:00:00', time) as result from yourtable
```